# How to create this urlManager rule?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

First of all, excuse my low english.

Having the following action in the controller named webController:

```
public function actionPage($view = 'index')
{
  try {
    return $this->render('site/page/' . $view);
  } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
    throw new HttpException(404);
  }
}
```

I need a rule to do the following:

```
localhost/cookies

equals

localhost/?r=web/page&view=cookiesyprivacidad
```

or

```
localhost/faq

equals

localhost/?r=web/page&view=preguntas
```

Something like this:

```
'rules'=>array(
   'cookies'=>'web/page'
)
```

But adding a fixed parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this

```
'urlManager' => array(
  'rules' => array(
    <view:(cookies|faq)>' => 'web/page'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would keep things little simple if I were you. I would create an action for each view in the controller as such and use urlmanager to route to proper controller action

```
'rules'=>array(
   'cookies'=>'page/cookiesyprivacidad',
   'faq'=>'page/preguntas',
)


public function actionCookiesyprivacidad()
{
  try {
    return $this->render('site/page/cookiesyprivacidad');
  } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
  throw new HttpException(404);
 }
}

 public function actionPreguntas()
{
  try {
    return $this->render('site/page/preguntas');
  } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
  throw new HttpException(404);
 }
}
```

Comment: But with this solution the above examples will always have the value "view" to index.

I think it's not possible to do what i attempt only with rules. Thanks

Comment: not really. when you have urls as such localhost/?r=web/page&view=cookiesyprivacidad, php will populate the $_GET variable with view = cookiesyprivacidad. give it a try and let us know if it worked or not.

Comment: The URL that should be in the browser is: localhost/cookies and internally transformed into: localhost/?r=web/page&view=cookiesyprivacidad

Comment: i made some changes in the answer above. it achieves what you want but not exactly the way you wanted.